# How is Data Science different to Computational Science

Tags: support, scope

Along the Vein of [How is Data Science Different From Cross-Validated?](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-is-data-science-different-from-cross-validated)

How is Data Science different to [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)?

I am feeling it sits somewhere between Computational Science and Cross Validated.
But I would like a nice clear answer, so that I can clearly tell anyone who asked me which site to post on.

Comment: Not attempting to give a full answer since I'm not that familiar with the other site but a quick look suggests there's not a whole lot of overlap. An analogy: we have questions about what road to take from A to B, they have questions about what car to drive.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** *data science* - focus is on **data**, *computational science* - focus is on **computation**.

While it sounds like words' play, I think that in this case the **emphasis** of each field is represented directly by the respective *adjective*. If you think about *semantics*, it's exactly that - the **focus** of *data science* is **data aspect** of application of *statistics* and *computer science* to corresponding problems, while, for *computational science*, the **focus** is most likely **algorithmic aspects** of the above-mentioned application.